# How to access Room database from different fragments?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

In my app I have a TabLayout and each of the tabs is represented by a fragment. I have several tables in a database. And for each table I want to have a tab that would display a list of table's contents. To access a database I need to pass in a context but it's only available from the MainActivity. How to access a database instance from each fragment?

Here's some code:
ElectronicsDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {Smartphone.class, Tablet.class,
        Laptop.class, VideoGameConsole.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class ElectronicsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract SmartphoneDao getSmartphoneDao();
    public abstract TabletDao getTabletDao();
    public abstract LaptopDao getLaptopDao();
    public abstract VideoGameConsoleDao getVideoGameConsoleDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "products.db";

    private static ElectronicsDatabase db;

    public static ElectronicsDatabase getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (db == null)
        {
            db =buildDatabaseInstance(context);
        }
        return db;
    }

    private static ElectronicsDatabase buildDatabaseInstance(Context context)
    {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, ElectronicsDatabase.class,
                DB_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }
}
```

And in the main activity I access it like this:

```
db = ElectronicsDatabase
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Try like `db = ElectronicsDatabase.getInstance(getContext());` from your fragment

Comment: And also how to access this database from a custom ArrayAdapter class?

Comment: its not recommended to use access your database in your adapter, use viewModel and pass your data to adapters.

Answer (score 3):

In your fragments you can use `getActivity()` to acccess context of your parent activity.

but i suggest you to use [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for accessing to your database.

Comment: I like your answer the most due to mentioning viewModels. I would just like to know, do you mean you store the Room Database instance in the viewModel and access it between fragments or is there another use for viewModels when it comes to Database access?

Comment: thanks. for getting more detail to answer your question just take look at this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **ViewModel** to access database in any activity or Fragment

ViewModel is a class that is responsible for preparing and managing the data for a UI component (activity or Fragment)

[image: Room database]

Answer (score 0):

In your case which is needing a Context for DB access via Room, it is better to pass a **non-UI Context** as to avoid unnecessary information being passed around for no reason leading to **possible memory leaks**.

You can get access to a non-UI Context which will be called ApplicationContext from your base activity, or your main activity. Simply like this:

```
Context appContext= getApplicationContext();
```

Then store it in a Repo class, so you can simply use it anytime you need it again anywhere without worrying about it.

However, if you need a context for something related to drawing on the screen, like inflating an XML for example, then in that case you will need a UI Context as not to lose UI details like your theme for example. In that case you can get the context from inside  your fragment using:

```
 getContext() Or getActivity().
```

I won't go to further details about contexts but,

if you want to learn more about what Context really is you can start from here:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/mastering-android-context-7055c8478a22

Answer (score 0):

That might be a very late answer, but I believe it might help some in the future:
If you are using multiple fragments and DI, you can create a viewModel for your activity, then inject the desired value into it

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PlantsRepository
): ViewModel() {
    private val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Plant>>()
    val liveData: LiveData<List<Plant>> = mutableLiveData // object to observe

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mutableLiveData.postValue(repository.getAllPlants())
            fillExampleData()
        }
    }
}
```

(sample for reference)

then you simply use it in your fragments:

```kotlin
class FragmentExampleScreen : Fragment() {

    private val sharedViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        ...

        sharedViewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { idk ->
            Log.i("hello", idk.toString())
        }
        ...
    }
}
```